# Unknown error code during application install: "920" while installing Google Keyboard

Tags: google-play-store, updates, settings

Unknown error code during application install: "920" while installing Google Keyboard on Android ver. 4.0.4

Comment: What's your question? Did you try re-installing?

Comment: Yes, tried re-installing twice and still when trying to update the apps the aforementioned error message continues to pop up, even cleared the data and the cache in the Google App Store settings and fully re-booted, still same thing.

Comment: Funny thing, this error message appeared for me when I tried to install Firefox. I've never seen this error before...

Answer (score 5):

Possible solutions:

- **Clear the cache *several times*.** `Settings > Apps > All > Google Play Store: Force Stop, Clear Data, Clear Cache`
- **Re-add Google account.**  `Settings > Accounts > Google > Click on your Gmail email address > Remove account`. Then, add it again.
- **Restart Wi-Fi connection.** Turn off Wi-Fi on your phone, and reconnect.

Sources:

- [Could not be downloaded due to an error (920)](http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-4/237331-could-not-downloaded-due-error-920-a.html)
- [Android Fix for error 920 or App could not be downloaded due to an error 920](http://appslova.com/android-fix-for-error-920-or-app-could-not-be-downloaded-due-to-an-error-920/)

Comment: Clear the cahce and data resolve the issue in my case. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

**Error 920 seems to be a server-side error.  Just wait 10-15 minutes and try again.**  This appears to happen most often if you download a bunch of apps from Google Play at once (like after you wipe your device).

I tried clearing my Google Play Store data and cache, restarting wifi, and rebooting to no avail. (I didn't try to remove and re-add my Google account, because that seemed too annoying.)

Source:
https://plus.google.com/+ArtemRussakovskii/posts/H82TA6h8YQA and experience.

Answer (score 1):

Could be because you added a new google account to your device. It should be resolved in a max of 30 min. If that doesn't work you can try clearing Play Store app data and cache.

Answer (score 0):

I cleared my data in WhatsApp and it worked for me.